# Is there any other method to do the following program in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to compare the values in two lists, If any value in the list1 greater than a value in list2, I need to increment the count and remove the compared values in list1 and list2. I shouldn't compare the same elements that were compared and satisfied the condition before.

I did this:

```
def main():

    list1 = list(map(int,input().split()))
    list2 = list(map(int,input().split()))

    list1.sort()
    list2.sort()
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for j in range(len(list2)):
            if list1[i] > list2[j]:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
    print(count)

main()
```

input:

```
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1 
2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 2 6
```

After sorting:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9]
[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]
```

my output:

```
49
```

Desired Output:

```
7
```

I tried to remove elements from the lists after satisfying the condition but I am getting "List index out of range" error.

Can anyone suggest a method to do this, I also tried the below method:

```
while len(list1) > 0:
    if list1[0] > list2[0]:
        count += 1
        list1.remove(list1[0])
        list2.remove(list2[0])
    else:
        break
print(count)
```

Output for the above method:

```
5
```

desired output:

```
7
```

Is there any other method to solve the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question simply asks how many elements in list1 is bigger than list2 considering the elements are removed.

You're doing repeated calculations by making that nested loop. Just store the minimum of list2, iterate over only list1 check if that element is higher than the minimum of list2 or not. If yes, add a counter and remove that element from list2. Complexity: O(mxn). If list2 is sorted, then we can binary search to find the index and remove it in O(log(n)). Then, complexity becomes O(mxlog(n))

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 9]
list2 = [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7, 9]


cnt = 0

for li in list1:
  mn = min(list2)
  if li > mn:
    cnt += 1
    list2.remove(mn)

print(cnt)
```

Ans: 7

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something like numpy, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.asarray([0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 7])

indices_to_keep = np.where((a - b) <= 0 )

count = len(a) - len(indices_to_keep[0])
new_a = a[indices_to_keep]
new_b = b[indices_to_keep]
print(count, new_a, new_b)
```

If you want to remove values from the original lists then you would replace `new_a` and `new_b` with `a` and `b` respectively. I should mention that this would work if your arrays have numerical types (which seems to be the case from your above example).